# QT QML what is the best approach for static layout

Tags: qt, layout, qml

I need a complete static layout with fixed positions and sizes like this.

[image]

Do I need a grid or column layout with relative positioning or can I work without any layout (only with x and y positioning and fixed sizes)?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [positioners](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-positioner.html) with `Rectangle`s that have the static size set to them like this.

```
Column {
    Rectangle { width: 100; height: 10; color: "#4472c4" }
    Row {
        Rectangle { width: 10; height: 60; color: "#8497b0" }
        Rectangle { width: 80; height: 60; color: "#a6a6a6" }
        Rectangle { width: 10; height: 60; color: "#333f50" }
    }
    Rectangle { width: 100; height: 10; color: "#d6dce5" }
}
```

You could also use `x` and `y` positioning without positioners.

```
Rectangle { width: 100; height: 10; color: "#4472c4" }
Rectangle { y: 10; width: 10; height: 60; color: "#8497b0" }
Rectangle { x: 10; y: 10; width: 80; height: 60; color: "#a6a6a6" }
Rectangle { x: 90; y: 10; width: 10; height: 60; color: "#333f50" }
Rectangle { y: 70; width: 100; height: 10; color: "#d6dce5" }
```

Or anchors

```
Rectangle { id: topRect; width: 100; height: 10; color: "#4472c4" }
Rectangle {
    id: leftRect
    anchors.top: topRect.bottom
    anchors.left: parent.left
    width: 10; height: 60; color: "#8497b0"
}
Rectangle {
    id: centerRect
    anchors.top: topRect.bottom
    anchors.left: leftRect.right
    x: 10; y: 10; width: 80; height: 60; color: "#a6a6a6"
}
Rectangle {
    id: rightRect
    anchors.top: topRect.bottom
    anchors.left: centerRect.right
    x: 90; y: 10; width: 10; height: 60; color: "#333f50"
}
Rectangle {
    id: bottomRect
    anchors.top: centerRect.bottom
    y: 70; width: 100; height: 10; color: "#d6dce5"
}
```

Or you could use layouts, but I prefer positioners over layouts.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using Layouts. The advantage is, whilst I gave the dimensions 100x80 container, the outer Rectangles needed minimal 10 pixel sizing information, whilst the inner most Rectangle didn't need any sizing, since, I made use of `Layout.fillWidth: true` and `Layout.fillHeight: true` as appropriate.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 100
        height: 80
        spacing: 0
        
        Rectangle {
            id: r1
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.preferredHeight: 10
            color: "blue"
        }
        
        RowLayout {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            spacing: 0
            
            Rectangle {
                id: r2
                Layout.preferredWidth: 10
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                color: "navy"
            }
            
            Rectangle {
                id: r5
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                color: "grey"
            }
            
            Rectangle {
                id: r4
                Layout.preferredWidth: 10
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                color: "darkblue"
            }
        }
        
        Rectangle {
            id: r3
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.preferredHeight: 10
            color: "lightsteelblue"
        }
    }
    
    Text {
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        
        text: `
R1: ${r1.width} x ${r1.height}
R2: ${r2.width} x ${r2.height}
R3: ${r3.width} x ${r3.height}
R4: ${r4.width} x ${r4.height}
R5: ${r5.width} x ${r5.height}
`
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAAF33icvZRNj4IwEIbv/IrG7JnIV7Lp1ctusofVbOLVCiM01paUsuoa/vtCq2AFSfazh6Yzz5B589IO3eVCKjRX85LGW4daoTsTXEnBitv8CzmKUhXOK0kBnRxUr5lg5Y4bcE41i/A4E7JwY+AK5DPHKCeyPrcFe5qoDCNvOm1TGdA0Uxg9dqkiJzHlKUZdqj0sIFaEpwyu2jaLJhhJz0oZee6GMrY0fZUsYagkl7ABKSF5OovxplZZLJiQGE3WrIRJS6oBdWLfM+VrUpqSi4pezYAxVvsxg1qT/F761oXl5S/dqxwVeW0YJ+/HiUWrHyiPxvTc8/U7slMJvyg7/EfDEyK39i211Q/d2bEXFfzxi2INLRQAG3pbZtfbGxyGJk290Y96bhE20zPnMnF6oPflWigldm29CfvuqLovRitn4WH0cJKeq0dYhQ4mMtOrcha+xr6F/Q4HGgcWDjocahxaOOxwpHFk4ajFq7NX1SduoIQR)